# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS freezes after coming out of lock mode with AMD Lucienne GPU on Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5

Tags: drivers, 22.04, suspend, lenovo, ideapad

I'm experiencing an issue where my Ubuntu freezes every time I try to come out of lock mode. It is not waking up after suspended. I can still move the mouse, but it does not open anything so I have to force a reboot to get it working again. Below are some information about my laptop

Hardware: Laptop with integrated AMD Lucienne GPU.
Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS].
Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5
Amd Ryzen 5 5000 series
After the last freeze, I used the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e and appeared:
out 22 12:39:40 manuela systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
out 22 12:39:40 manuela kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
out 22 12:39:40 manuela systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~

Anyone who had the same problem and could help me, please?